# How to load canvas data to a string only if user draws something on it using angular?

Tags: angular, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to store canvas data to a variable in Angular only if the user draws or makes any changes to it.

I'm not getting how to do this automatically.

My component.html file looks something like this:

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

My component.ts file looks something like this:

```js
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

@Component({
  selector: "app-drawspace",
  templateUrl: "./drawspace.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./drawspace.component.css"]
})
export class DrawspaceComponent implements OnInit {
canvasData: any;
constructor(){}
canvas: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { 
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    selection: false,
    isDrawingMode: true
  });
 }
 // I want this loadjson() to to be called automatically whenever a user draws something on the canvas
 loadjson() {
  this.canvasData = JSON.stringify(this.canvas);
  console.log(this.canvasData);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leverage the `path:created` event of the fabric js library.

Try the following

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  canvasData: any;
  constructor() {}
  canvas: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      width: 1000,
      height: 500,
      selection: false,
      isDrawingMode: true
    });

    // Reason for `bind(this)`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/6513921
    this.canvas.on('path:created', this.loadjson.bind(this));
  }

  loadjson() {
    this.canvasData = JSON.stringify(this.canvas);
    console.log(this.canvasData);
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wsbib6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

There's a plethora of other [fabric js events](http://fabricjs.com/events) that you could look into.

Comment: Hey, Its not calling loadjson when a image is added into the canvas. I don't know why.

Comment: @Avatar: I'm not sure how you're adding the image to the canvas, but as the name implies `path:created` event is triggered when a user draws something on the canvas. And as mentioned in the answer, if you look at other events, the one you're looking for might be `object:added`. Try: `this.canvas.on('object:created', this.loadjson.bind(this));`. If this too doesn't work, try to use other events mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I tried `this.canvas.on('object:created', this.loadjson.bind(this))` but this doesn't work, so looked into docs and tried `this.canvas.on('object:added', this.loadjson.bind(this))` , this is creating a infinite loop. And I'm adding image using button which in turn triggers a function and it uploads the image to firebase storage and returns a imageurl, and by `fabric.Image.fromURL(this.imgURL, function(img) { canvas.add(img);})` I'm adding the image.